# Reading lines from an asset file

Tags: android

So I thought I had everything right, but apparently I do not. Below is the buggy function and it does not read the line right. The file "save.txt" is located in the assets folder with only the word "new" in it at the very top. This loadGame function will print "load" to logcat which is not correct because the word new is the first line in the file. Also sending br.readLine() to the log will crash the application so it definitely is not reading the right thing.

```
private boolean loadGame() {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            is = am.open("save.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            if(br.readLine() != "new") {
                //More parsing will go here
                Log.d("test", "load");
                return(true);
            } else {
                Log.d("test", "new");
                return(false);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return(false);
    }
```

Comment: Try !br.readLine().equals("new")

Comment: Want that works thanks you, is there a reason I cannot do Log.d("test", br.readLine()); ? because readLine returns a string it says.

Comment: You can do that. just wrap it in a try catch block. bcz `br.readLine()` may throw an `IOException`

Comment: Glad I could help. I have posted it as answer, gladly mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

@Want2bExpert ans is correct but why your code is not working or what is problem in your code for this understood below concept :

`==` is used compare `Object` reference.

`equals/equalsIgnoreCase` are used to compare `Object` value.

So when you compare two `String` try to use second option instead of first.

Examples :

```
String s1 = "string1";
String s2 = "string2";
String s3 = "string1";
String s4 = s2;

if(s1 == s2) -> false
if(s1.equals(s2)) -> false
if(s1 ==  s3) -> false
if(s1.equals(s3)) - > true
if(s2 == s3) -> false
if(s2 == s4) -> true
if(s2.equals(s4)) - > true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use equals in place of "=" as below  !br.readLine().equals("new")